# How to trigger azure yml pipeline on tagging master branch only

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

Regarding azure yml pipeline trigger

How to achieve below requirements
I want to trigger my azure yml pipeline

- Should trigger pipeline on master branch if PR is merged to master branch
- Should trigger pipeline on master branch if git tag is added on master branch.
- Should not trigger pipeline if git tag is added on non-master branches (like develop, features branches)
- Should trigger pipeline on non-master branches if PR is merged or commit happens on these branches

How to handle this any idea, I have below trigger set as of now?

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - master
    - features/*
  paths:
    exclude:
    - README.md
    - azure-pipelines.yml
  tags:
    include:
    - refs/tags/*-RELEASE
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Azure DevOps Service, the yaml build just trigger current branch, such as the `.yml` file in the dev branch, and add Push trigger `trigger - master`, then push code in the master branch, it will not trigger the build.

As a workaround, we need to update the `.yml` content in the different branch.

For example, If we create YAML build in the master branch, it will create `azure-pipelines.yml` file in the master branch.

- Should trigger pipeline on master branch if PR is merged to master branch
- Should trigger pipeline on master branch if git tag is added on master branch.

We can do this by adding the following push triggers

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  tags:
    include:
    - refs/tags/*-RELEASE
```

- Should not trigger pipeline if git tag is added on non-master branches (like develop, features branches)
- Should trigger pipeline on non-master branches if PR is merged or commit happens on these branches

Then create branch develop and features, it also contain the file `azure-pipelines.yml`, edit the file content.

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
    - develop #in the develop enter develop, in the feature branch, we need to update it to feature.
  tags:
    exclude:
    - refs/tags/*-RELEASE
```

**Update1**

[image]

Comment: Will this really work? [Docs on tag filters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?&tabs=yaml#tags) says that _"If you specify tags in combination with branch filters, the trigger will fire if either the branch filter is satisfied or the tag filter is satisfied. For example, if a pushed tag satisfies the branch filter, the pipeline triggers even if the tag is excluded by the tag filter, because the push satisfied the branch filter."_ In your last example if a commit is done on the `develop` branch, it will run even if it is tagged with `RELEASE`?

Comment: Also, how to handle mergers and PR's when maintaining different `azure-pipelines.yml` files on different branche? For example when taking out a new feature branch from master the `azure-pipelines.yml` needs to be edited. When merged back it will overwrite what is in master with the name of the feature branch, and pipeline will not be triggered for the the new commit(s) on master since that now contains a trigger for the feature branch rather than master

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I just test the submitted code and add tags separately. If you create new branch based on `devlop` branch, push code and add tag `release`, then create Pull Request and merge the code, it will trigger the build, the build is triggered by the latest commit ("Merge PR Commit"), it will not check other commit tags.

Comment: In the different branches, the file `azure-pipelines.yml` is different, the file `azure-pipelines.yml` will conflict when we create PR, we could use extension [Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab) to resolve the conflict and choose to keep the target branch file. content

Comment: but this yml pipeline should be common across the branches.

Comment: Hi @sanjesh, the yml pipeline is not common across the branches, we switch the yaml pipeline via change the branch, check the Update1 pic.

Comment: Hi @sanjesh, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Yes i am still looking for good solution. We have single azure yml file (Trunk base deployment) and do not want multiple yml file per branches